# JSON.parse() not working in javascript in pentaho

Tags: javascript, json, pentaho, kettle

I am trying to form an array from a string using Modified Java Script Value step. Here is my code to parse a string and to form a JSON object.

```
var info = {};
var keywords = 'Adjust course (C-6),Identify underlying factors (C-4),Isolate teacher actions (C-3_)';
if(keywords != null && keywords != ''){
keywords = keywords.replace(/,/g,'","');
keywords = '["'+keywords+'"]';
info.keywords = JSON.parse(keywords);
}
```

Here in JSON.parse() it throws an error SyntaxError: Missing comma in array literal.

Can anyone please help me parse the array and store in json object.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I executed your code in the Chrome dev console and it works fine. Also in JavaScript you can compact the if clause like so: if(keywords){...}

Comment: You also can use `eval` function, but be careful!

Comment: @Arunraj Please show what should you want to get after this code, I think that have more correct solution for you

Comment: Can you `console.log(keywords)` before parsing in your environment and tell what is it?

Comment: java.lang.System.out.println(keywords);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
if(keywords){
  keywords = keywords.split(',');
  info.keywords = keywords;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function kwInfo(text)
{
    return JSON.parse('["' + (text || '').split(',').join('","') + '"]');
}

var text = 'Adjust course (C-6),Identify underlying factors (C-4),Isolate teacher actions (C-3_)';
var info = {keywords:kwInfo(text)};

console.log(info);
```

Comment: Make sure you're using a (respectable) modern (updated) web browser, like: Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, etc.

Comment: this is not  regular javascript, and pentaho is not a browser.  its the rhino js engine isolated

Answer (score 0):

Run kettle in console mode SpoonConsole.bat

```
var info = {};
var keywords = 'Adjust course (C-6),Identify underlying factors(C-4),Isolate 
teacher actions (C-3_)';

java.lang.System.out.println("Original : " + keywords);

if(keywords != null && keywords != ''){
   keywords = keywords.replace(/,/g,'","');
   java.lang.System.out.println("Regexp applied : " + keywords);
   keywords = '["'+keywords+'"]';
   java.lang.System.out.println(keywords);
   info.keywords = JSON.parse(keywords);
}
```

Look into console and trace the error in logic

This is only way I found to trace JavaScript step